Is it possible to use GET/HEAD Object with partNumber parameter for incomplete multipart uploads?
I noticed here that AWS says you can get part for an incomplete mpu, but in practice doesn't doing this always return a not found error? Are the docs incorrect here?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/checking-object-integrity.html#large-object-checksums

I tried get object with partNumber for incomplete MPU, it returned Not found error, I expected it to return the part object.

That documentation does appear to be incorrect.  To get this information you'll need to call ListMultipartUploads to get the in progress uploads (or know this via other means) and use ListParts to get the information on each part.
